# Domain join machine with account that has expired password

Tags: windows-domain

Does anyone know if there is a policy that controls if an account is allowed to join a domain, if the account has an expired password?

I am working with Azure templates to provision machines and have them join our domain.  Everything has been working fine with our service account and new provisioned machines are joining the domain.  However, it appears that the service account has an expired password.

Is this the expected behavior?  Is there a policy to prevent this?

Comment: You don't typically join service accounts on a machine to the domain

Comment: I've created plenty of domain accounts for use as service accounts. They're really helpful when you have systems using processing on multiple systems, such as a database running on one server and a connected application running elsewhere. You generally give them very long and complex passwords, and set them never to expire.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you are using domain accounts to run services, you can and should set their passwords to never expire unless there is a strong reason not to in your specific case.

I may be assuming too much, but it sounds as though you're not the one creating the accounts. If this is the case you should talk to the person who creates accounts and see if they can create service accounts without requiring password expiration.

However, if you're the one creating accounts and you know there is not a policy on the domain requiring every user account password to change on a schedule, in the Account Properties you should be able to select "Password never expires" for the service accounts.

Comment: This more for an app I am developing.  We ask the user for their service account info, and we use that to domian join new machines.  We noticed that this was working, but when tried to validate that same password with another system, we got an error saying the password expired.  We were just wondering if this is globally allowed or if there is a policy to prevent it.

Comment: Then you'll need to get your client to update the password for the service account and get you the new one, and probably ask them if they can create an account whose password does not expire for these purpose.